# WPF Designer says "Build the Project to update Design view" while not needed

Tags: c#, wpf

So this photo is pretty self explaining itself:

[image]

The RowNumberConverter DOES exist in the same namespace but Visual Studio stupidly says that it doesn't!
I did clean the solution and the app builds and runs with no problems but I can't see the designer! And all of this happened suddenly with no reason no idea why!

BTW that's a converter class for showing row numbers in an EntityFramework-binded DataGrid.

‌
‌
‌
**Update:**

Converter file (RowNumberConverter.cs):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace MyProject
{
    class RowNumberConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        #region IMultiValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {

            //get the grid and the item
            Object item = values[0];
            DataGrid grid = values[1] as DataGrid;

            int index = grid.Items.IndexOf(item);

            return (index < 0) ? "" : (index + 1).ToString();
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: *"this photo is pretty self explaining"* No it's not. Just because IntelliSense is picking it up from code doesn't mean the designer can use the compiled version. Is it in another assembly or in the same? If it's another assembly - does the assembly target the same .Net version?

Comment: Could you show the xaml of `RowNumberConverter`?

Comment: And your namespace-definitions. Even if the C# namespace is the same, if it's in another assembly, you'll need a separate XML namespace.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It's totally the same .NET version, same solution, same project, same namespace, a simple .cs converter class file...

Comment: @MattBeldon It's not a xaml, it's a .cs converter class file, I'll update the question with the .cs file.

Comment: This is typical VS. You have to live with it. Most of the time it helps, cleaning and rebuilding. If that didn't help change the mode from Debug to Release. and back to Debug.

Comment: Stupid question, but have you restarted VS yet? That usually helps.

Comment: if you have `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"` it should be seeing it

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Like, a thousand times :))

Comment: @MattBeldon Exactly, It's there and still I'm struggling

Comment: `Top menu bar > Build > Clean Solution` && `Top menu bar > Build > Rebuild Solution`

Comment: @NawedNabiZada Putting in Release mode and running the project worked, but back to debug, back to bug!

Comment: @MattBeldon Tried that too, no luck..

Comment: Deleting bin/Debug didn't help either. I guess I'll have to continue debugging in Release mode!

Comment: I wonder if this was solved @ParSa.  I run into exactly the same issue.....

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Also w/ a converter. I am building x64 only, debug or release. Are you building AnyCPU?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has been an issue w/ VS for a long, long time. You need to set the build type to be "Any CPU" or x86, anything that is NOT x64. This is because (for reasons nobody understands), since VS is built from x86 code, it cannot show and display x64 code in the designer. Switch (temporarily) your project to x86, recompile, and presto, it will show up!

Comment: Not sure why nobody up-voted this answer. This is THE only solution that works. No switching back and forth, no cleaning or rebuilding of the entire solution. Just building the project itself with build type "Any CPU" as suggested. Sometimes one should celebrate the "winners" more.

Comment: Yes I've tried all solutions from many different posts and this is the only solution.

Comment: well, I DO work at Microsoft. I asked the VS head honcho about this and got the answer from him. Heh.

Comment: `Any CPU` didn't worked for me as well - but `x86` works! This may occur, because we have unmanaged `x64` references in the project.

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/603258/vs-2019-wpf-designer-x64-app-configuration-bug-doe.html